# Use of triangle inequality for 2 triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangulation

[image]

In what angles of $\hat a, \hat b, \hat c, \hat d$ below conditions hold

1) $|AC+AD|>|BC+BD|$  or

1) $|AC+AD|<|BC+BD|$

Comment: @S.B. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe use the law of sines applied to the angles a,b,c,d and maybe also 180-b-c and 180-a-d, to get all lengths in terms of AB. Then the comparisons can be made on factoring out the length AB. But this might get messy.

Comment: This I believe has to do with the scalene inequality. The larger the angle the larger the side opposite the angle is larger and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the law of sines in triangle ABC we have 
$$\frac{AC}{\sin b}=\frac{AB}{\sin c}=\frac{BC}{\sin(b+c)},$$
where we have used that the angle at A in triangle ABC is $180-b-c$, and the fact that $\sin(180-x)=\sin x.$ Similarly applying the law of sines to triangle ABD we have
$$\frac{BD}{\sin a}=\frac{AB}{\sin d}=\frac{AD}{\sin(a+d)}.$$
This gives the four desired lengths all in terms of the angles and $AB$ as
$$AC=AB\frac{\sin b}{\sin c},\\
BC=AB\frac{\sin(b+c)}{\sin c},\\
BD=AB \frac{\sin a}{\sin d},\\
AD=AB\frac{\sin(a+d)}{\sin d}.$$
We now may substitute these into the inequality $AC+AD>BC+BD$ and cancel the common (positive) factor $AB$, to obtain the angle criterion
$$\frac{\sin b}{\sin c}+\frac{\sin(a+d)}{\sin d} >
\frac{\sin(b+c)}{\sin c}+\frac{\sin a}{\sin d}.$$
This cannot be simplified much, apart from maybe giving names to the third angles to the two triangles, or clearing denominators, etc. Of course the other inequality $AC+AD<BC+BD$ is equivalent to the above with the inequality reversed.

Side note: There is equality iff the two points $A,B$ lie on the same ellipse with foci at $C,D.$

Comment: Any idea for this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450702/triangle-inequality-for-a-complex-triangle

Comment: @Norman That other question looks more difficult as it seems hard to use the law of sines to get all lengths in terms of a single length. I'll look more at it...

Comment: many thanks. Yeah it might be a very messy equation.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456539/number-of-relationships-between-angles-and-lengths

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458501/equation-of-an-intersection-of-two-cones-when-the-intersection-is-an-ellipse