# Equation of an intersection of two cones when the intersection is an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

[image]

The two cones with vertex $A=(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ and $B=(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})$ and generating angle of two cones is $\alpha$ given.

I need to write the equation of the intersection of two cones when the intersection is an ellipse?

Comment: @coffeemath any thoughts?

Comment: The vectors pointing from A and B which are axes of symmetry of the two cones would also be needed, not just the positions of $A,B$ and the value of the angle $\alpha.$ Then maybe set each cone up using dot product. But it looks like it would be quite involved.